# CW Complexes are Locally Path Connected: Rotman's Proof

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, cw-complexes

I found [Rotman's proof](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4576-6) rather fiddly, and my question is why he doesn't do it in the following easier way (probably because I am missing something):

He has already proved (actually, the proof is left to exercises, but these come *before* his proof of local path connectedness),  that if $X$ is a $CW$ complex then

$1),\ $ there is an increasing sequence $\{X^n\}_{n\ge 0}$ of sets whose union is $X$, ($X$ has the weak topology induced by the $X^n), \ X^0$ is discrete and

$2).\ $  for each integer $n$ there is a family of continuous functions $\{f_{\alpha}^{n-1}: S^{n-1}\to X^{n-1}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ such that $X^n=\left(\coprod_{\alpha} D^n\right)\coprod_f X^{n-1}$ where $f=\coprod_{\alpha} f_{\alpha}^{n-1}.$

In particular, $2). $ says that $X^n$ is obtained from a quotient of the disjoint union of $\coprod_{\alpha} D^n$ and $X^{n-1}.$

Now, $X^0$ is (trivially) locally path connected, and it's easy to show that the disjoint union of locally path connected spaces is locally path connected, so if we can show that the quotient of a locally path connect space is locally path connected, then an induction gives what I believe is an alternative, easier proof. Or am I missing something?

But this is not hard:

Suppose $p:X\to Y$ is a quotient map and $X$ is locally path connected. Take an open $V\subseteq Y$ and let $C$ be path component of $V.$ If $x\in p^{-1}(C)$ then $x\in p^{-1}(V)$ also so there is an open path connected $U\subseteq p^{-1}(V)$ containing $x$ (since $X$ is locally path connected).

Now, if $u\in U$ there is a path $\varphi: [0,1]\to U$ such that $\varphi(0)=x$ and $\varphi(1)=u.$ It follows that $p\circ \varphi:[0,1]\to V$ is a path such that $p\circ \varphi(0)=p(x)$ and $p\circ \varphi(1)=p(u).$ But $p(x)\in C$ and this forces $p(u)\in C$ as well, so that in fact $\varphi([0,1])\subseteq p^{-1}(C).$ But then $u\in p^{-1}(C).$

Putting all this together, we see that $U\subseteq p^{-1}(C)$, which means that $p^{-1}(C)$ is open in $X$ and therefore that $C$ is open in $Y$ (since $Y$ has the quotient topology). So $C$ is an open, path connected set contained in $V.$ We conclude that $Y$ is locally path connected.

Comment: Just so you know, you can use markdown formatting to make bold/italic text instead of using \textit in math mode - I adjusted that for you, as well as removing the algebraic-geometry tag which wasn't very applicable to your topological question.

Comment: @KReiser: ok thanks. My development skills don't go much beyond basic python--

Comment: No need to know any development skills to use Markdown - [here's a tutorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and it's the same sort of formatting you can see at many websites/forums these days.

Comment: @KReiser: Yes, indeed. These tools are very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good to me.

I don't have Rotman's book so I don't know what he does, but I'll say this: I don't think your technique extends to prove the local contractibility of CW complexes. The proof of the latter property is indeed quite a bit more complicated or "fiddly" as you put it, making use of the specific union expressions in properties (2) and (3).